# Get result from Share Via dialog

Tags: android, webview, long-press

```
public boolean onLongClick(View v)  {

      Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Text here - " );
        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, viewContentWebView.getUrl());

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Link Goes to..."));
        return true;  
}
```

Hi all,
With that code im trying to share webview's link with longpress.
So, the user will press on webview for a while and will get "share via" menu.

But how could I get any result?

Comment: What result do you want? ACTION_SEND does not normally return any useful information.

Comment: hi, i want to share the link which is currently using by webview but with longclick. so, when the user will press on webview, i wanted to see "share via" dialog, but i could not.

Comment: Your code seems to be doing that already. What is not working?

Comment: i dont know. when i do on a real device i cannot get any result. i think maybe i need to define webview in that code. because the codes re in webview.java but the perhaps the app cant resolve the code for what.